# Can one _see_ one's private key in, and _transcribe_ it out of ... a laptop wallet?

Tags: private-key

Suppose I download bitcoin wallet software, or Armory, and create a new account, on my laptop. Can I see and transcribe the newly-created private key?   Then suppose I receive some Bitcoin into this new wallet-on-laptop. If I transcribe the private key I can see onto durable media, (a paper wallet, coldsteel device, or some other durable material), then I could remove the wallet software from my laptop completely and be left with a hard wallet, offline and very secure.  But does the latest Bitoin Core wallet or Armory wallet show (display), or let the user see that private key?

Comment: yes, at least in bitcoin core you can. And Electrum is similiar, not sure about Armory though. Search for "export of private key", this is what is required to move funds. Search the forum here for export private key, and you will see many answers, which give you a hint how to go forward :-)

Comment: You could do this, but it is not advised. You shouldn't generate private keys on devices which you may connect to the internet.

Comment: Thank you both. This was a generic question. The key I need to see pronto is in a 2011 copy of Bitcoin on a 2011 era laptop. I'm at the mercy of old equipment and old software. I won't really have control of the balance until I control that private key, hence my question. pebwindkraft I'll look for "export private key" in the 2011 software. I'm really after getting control of the old private key.

Comment: Nope. There's no "export private key" in Bitcoin 0.3.24-beta.